# Jquery line through tr in php dynamic foreach table using checkbox

Tags: php, jquery

I'm trying to strike through a tr when a checkbox is checked. I can do this if I know the id of a given row but my table is generated by a PHP foreach loop. The following codes works but all rows have a line through each td. I only want the row with the checkbox selected.

```
<script>
    $('input.complete').on('click', function(e) {
        if (this.checked) {

            $("td").addClass('newclass');
        } else {

            $("td").removeClass('newclass');
        }
    });
</script>
```

The table is generated by the following PHP foreach loop:

```
<?php foreach ($tasks as $task):?>
    <tr>
       <td><?php echo $task->id;?></td>
       <td rowid="<?php echo $task->id;?>"><?php echo $task->task_name;?></td>
       <td><?php echo $task->task_desc;?></td>
       <td><input  class="complete" type="checkbox" name="complete" value="CheckBox"></td>
     </tr>
 <?php endforeach;?>
```

The css is simply:

```
.newclass {
        text-decoration: line-through;
    }
```

I have tried to isolate the rows using parent and child selectors but can't seem to solve it. How do I get just the checked row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(this).parent().siblings("td").addClass("newclass");
```

would be the way to specify only the `<td>`'s in the respective row.

You'll need to change the removeClass line as well.

Comment: Yep, that's is it. I tried a few variations on that but nothing worked. Your solution is spot on. Thanks very much.